# Lookup Column (Header) name in Excel for a given cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have one workbook with many order numbers in many different columns(20+). Each Column has a different Header(column name) that can be found in the first row.

On a different sheet I will have all of the order numbers compiled into column A. In column B I would populate the name of the column (header) for each order number.

The code below would provide me a function to return the sheet name. In line 14 I tried changing w.s. name to header but it would not work.

```
Option Explicit
Function FindMyOrderNumber(strOrder As String) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Application.Volatile
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName <> "Sheet3" Then
            Set rng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strOrder, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
Next

Set rng = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Cells(1, rng.Column)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you want to return the same value you're passing into the function...

If you mean you want to return the column letter where the header was found then edit the lines below:

```
'On Error Resume Next 'don't need this...
Set rng = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=strOrder, LookAt:=xlWhole)
'On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    FindMyOrderNumber = Replace(rng.Address(False, False),"1","")
    Exit For
End If
```

**EDIT:** To return the value in the cell below the header:

```
'On Error Resume Next 'don't need this...
Set rng = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=strOrder, LookAt:=xlWhole)
'On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    FindMyOrderNumber = rng.Offset(1,0).Value
    Exit For
End If
```

Comment: I imported a columns from other excel sheets to get my order numbers. In row 1 in the excel sheet there is the name of each columns that named via SQL. It would have the project name and who is assigned. So not the letter like A but the value under it. I am sorry I do not know the terminology.